# MSBuild Community Tasks - ILMerge invalid command line switch path1

Tags: msbuild, ilmerge

I am trying to use ILMerge in a C# project file to combine some dlls into a single dll (for various reasons). I have downloaded MSBuild Community Tasks from https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks, which has a target for ILMerge.

I am getting this obscure error message when trying to use the ILMerge target:

```
"C:\svn\AwaitingFeedbackCanceller.csproj" (rebuild target) (1) ->
(Zip target) ->
C:\svn\AwaitingFeedbackCanceller.csproj(150,5): error MSB6001: Invalid command line switch for "ILMerge.exe".
Value cannot be null.\r
C:\svn\AwaitingFeedbackCanceller.csproj(150,5): error MSB6001: Parameter name: path1
```

These are the relevant bits from my project file:

```
    <PropertyGroup>
    <ZipFileName>$(ProjectName)-$([System.String]::Copy('$(projectguid)').Trim('\{\}')).zip</ZipFileName>
    <MergedFile>$(ProjectDir)$(ProjectName).dll</MergedFile>
    <logFile>$(ProjectDir)$(ProjectName).log</logFile>
    <TargetPlatformVersion>v4</TargetPlatformVersion>
    <TargetPlatformDirectory>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319</TargetPlatformDirectory>
    </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <inputAssemblies Include="$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)$(AssemblyName).dll" />
    <inputAssemblies Include="$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)AeriandiGeminiPluginBase.dll" />
    <allowDuplicates Include="$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)ClassAB" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Target Name="Merge">
    <Message Importance="high" Text="Merging assemblies" />
    <ILMerge InputAssemblies="@(inputAssemblies)" AllowDuplicateTypes="@(allowDuplicates)" OutputFile="$(MergedFile)" LogFile="$(logFile)" DebugInfo="true" XmlDocumentation="true" TargetPlatformVersion="$(TargetPlatformVersion)" TargetPlatformDirectory="$(TargetPlatformDirectory)" />
    </Target>
```

This is really starting to hold me up as I need to automate the deployment of a number of projects.

Can anyone point me to what I am doing wrong?

Cheers,

Ashley

Disclosure: I have also added this question to the issues on Github for this project but have not had a response - https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks/issues/42.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get this to work, I had to install the IlMerge MSI. I was trying to use a NuGet version with the ToolPath specified but it still could not find IlMerge for some reason.

After installing the msi version, it worked fine.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17630

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as you describe above, but by adding this ToolPath to the NuGet version of ILMerge task I was able to make it work:

```
<ILMerge ToolPath="packages\ilmerge.2.13.0307" ...
```